# How to replace "zero" value to a table in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

This is My phpmyadmin panel

[image]

I want to Clear "Points" value of all users at a time, For Example There : Points value is "744" so i want to clear this all of my users.

Comment: Use [`UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = 0 WHERE meta_key = 'points';
```

This should set the meta_value to 0 for all rows where the meta_key is points. Thank **Ergest Basha** for pointing out the discrepancy in the previous answer.